# Scattered loading of Slider images on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a jquery image slider.I have added four images into this slider.Now there is a very weird and bad thing coming out of this slider is that All the four images are displaying one after another vertically while loading of the page Which is giving very bad user experience.

Here is the jquery code that i have written to make this slider working..

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            mode: 'fade',
            adaptiveHeight: 'true',
            speed: 3000,
            easing: 'ease-in-out',
            auto: true,
            autoHover: true,
            pager: false

        });

    });

</script>
```

Please help me to resolve this... Thanks

Comment: did you add any css files?

Comment: @mathf Yes they are very big ..

Comment: Do you get this behaviour only while the page is loading? Or is the slider not working at all (showing all images instead of only one)?

Comment: @mathf I am getting this behaviour while the page is loading.Slider is working properly

Comment: @mathf R u helping me sir..